# Replace all text from <A> to </a> link

Tags: phpmyadmin, calc, find-replace

Hello i have lot of trash in wordpress posts and i have to remove content from

```
<a href....> SPORT Basket </a> ......
```

I try some like   `<a*</a>`   replace via openoffice calc (find and replace) Basically i need to remove the tag  and all the text (sport basket) inside , also the close of the tag A

There are lot of different words inside so i think about:

```
  (from) <a (all here via * )  ..... to ...when find close tag </a>    ..... replace with &nbsp;
```

remove all inside quote ex:

```
'<a href="httpxxxxx"> trash info </a> '
```

Need to remove all (it is a simple a tag)

Hope i explain my problem.

Comment: You almost certainly should be using DOM methods rather than regex, but we'll need more information for this to be answerable:  do you want to remove *all* the links from the page?  If not, is there a clear way to identify which links you want to remove and which you don't? (i.e. do they have the same class name, or link to the same page, or are all in the same part of the page, or have some innertext in common, or something?)

Comment: there are like 200 posts, i try to migrate to another website but in wp_column in database, i found some trash in some posts. So, open with a notepad and see there is bad link in some posts. i need to delete all from <a href .... to .... </a>

i try also to add a YYY near for easy delete but i can't get it. 
I need to remove all from YYY to YYY

YYY<a href="http://wwww.com">some_text_to_delete</a>YYY